# What ways are there make HTML modular?

Tags: html

HTML often has repeating and independent structures that are modular on a theoretical level, such as multiple portfolio-items:

```
<div class="protfolio-item">
        <div class="image">
            <a ...><img /></a>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-content">
            <h2>...</h2>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Even writing them out feels stupid. Now I want to make a change, like having an icon superposed on every picture. What ways are there to achieve more modular code that's easier to change? Are there any non-PHP "native" ways to do so?

Comment: You mean like [`mustache`](http://mustache.github.io/)? You mentioned PHP though, you're better off using a templating engine server-side and keeping the strain (and support headaches) out of the equation (rather than using something like JavaScript and wondering if the client can benefit).

Comment: There is no native HTML templating nor is there any native templating period, but there are a *ton* of both server and client side templating engines.  This was actually the reason php was invented in the first place, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-PHP, native? The first thing I can think of is `Server Side Includes` - not very powerful but you can divide your document into pieces making it modular. The main disadvantage is lack of loops.